# Append a row to the end of an (.xlsx) document

Tags: python, excel, csv

**Objective:**
Appending a row to an .xlsx document using Python (3.7).

What I wish to append to the last row of Document.xlsx (cell delimiter: " | "):

```
(Last_Row): [Tom] | [Tablet] | [003332] | [Returned] | [PSEA]
```

Document.xlsx:

```
[] [  A  ] | [   B   ] | [   C   ] | [    D   ] | [    E   ]
1: [FIID:] | [Device:] | [Gov_ID:] | [ Status ] | [Project:]
2: [John ] | [Laptop ] | [002435 ] | [Resigned] | [  AWSD  ]
...
+4,000 rows
```

What I have so far is appending from a (.csv) document.

Pulling_Data_CSV.py

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\...\Test_Pandas.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Tom", "Laptop", "003332", "Returned", "AWSD"])
```

What is the equivalent for editing a .xlsx document?

If that is not possible, how would I convert a .xlsx to .csv, append a row, then convert it back to a .xlsx document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io):

```
import openpyxl

filename = 'C:\\temp\\spreadsheet.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
new_row = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']

sheet.append(new_row)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you! Now I got to add a border to the appended row, but I can look that up in the documentation for openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

xlsx is a complex container format, based on xml. You could parse that yourself, but likely you want to check out a module like openpyxl and go from there.

Comment: Looking up the documentation for openpyxl, thank you. pointed me into the right direction.